# awk + how to count lines with apecific structure

Tags: linux, awk

How do I use `awk` to count all lines adhering to the following structure:

```
"any-string" : "any-string"
```

For example

```
      "ssl.server.keystore.type" : 
      "mapred-logsearch-conf" : {
      "hive.server2.thrift.sasl.qop" : "auth",
      "hive.merge.orcfile.stripe.level" : "true",
      "hive.orc.splits.include.file.footer" : "false",
      "hive.exec.compress.output" : "false",
      "hive.user.install.directory" : "/user/",
      "hive.prewarm.enabled" : "false",
      "hive.compactor.delta.num.threshold" : "10",
      "hive.orc.compute.splits.num.threads" : "10",
      "hive.vectorized.groupby.checkinterval" : "4096",
      "properties_attributes" : { },
```

would produce the output "9".

Comment: This seems to be a `json`-format, and if it is, you definitely do _not_ want to parse it by lines, since there is not guarantee that the line feeds will be there.

Comment: yes but not have choice all tools as json2csv etc cant read my json

Comment: Is there something wrong with your json?

Comment: I think yes , but not have idea how to fix it - this is very long file ( 7634 line s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you ask an `awk` code, here is one:

```
awk '/"[^"]*"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"[^"]*"/ { n++ } END { print n }'
```

But `grep` is more appropriate for this:

```
grep -c '"[^"]*"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*"[^"]*"'
```

Comment: is it possible only capture the lines ( print all the lines ) ? with awk

Comment: Of course, replace `n++` with `print; n++`

Answer (score 0):

To print matched lines use the `print` command inside the matched block. The example below does the print and the count-:

```
awk '/\".*\"[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*\".*\"/{print;n++} END{print n}'
```

ps -  you should update your question regarding the print requirement.